# Oracle database on virtual box

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, linux-mint, database

Happy New Year to Everyone!

My OS is linux mint.

**What I want to do:**
I want to install oracle database on virtual box and interact with it using the oracle sql developer installed on host os (mint).

**What I have done so far:**
I have installed Virtual Box. I have downloaded Oracle DB Developer VM from Oracle official site and and imported it into Virtual box. This includes a preinstalled oracle database.

How can I proceed?
Or does anyone have any alternative idea on installing oracle database directly on host OS (I would prefer this, but know ubuntu based distros are not supported!).

Thank you.